# An polynomial time algorithm to solve LP

Tags: linear-programming, polytopes

Is there a polynomial time algorithm that gives the extreme point as output for which objective function is minimized/maximized ? I am not looking for any solution that minimizes/maximizes the objective function, but an extreme point of the feasible region for which objective function is minimized/maximized.

Comment: polynomial with respect to what ? the number of dimensions (of variables) ? of constraints ? and the interior point method can only give an approximation of the optimum, I don't think there is a simple algorithm for  transforming that approximate solution to a vertex of the admissible polytope (an exact solution)

Comment: The min/max is always at an extreme point, or a hyperplane containing extreme points... so what is the distinction suggested by "not looking for any solution to max/min" versus just giving extreme point? Also I think simplex only goes through a linear number of tableaus, not all of them, but don't know if this means polynomial time in your sense.

Comment: @coffeemath : [the worst case of the simplex is not polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Efficiency) (in the usual sense of polynomial) "It is an open question if there is a variation with polynomial time, or even sub-exponential worst-case complexity"

Comment: from wikipedia page of ellipsoid method "Following Khachiyan's work, the ellipsoid method was the only algorithm for solving linear programs whose runtime had been proved to be polynomial until Karmarkar's algorithm". I am not sure what ellipsoid method does. Does it produce an optimal solution to the maximizing problem? It is not necessary that only vertex of polytope produce optimal solutions.